# Rails basic edit form submits but doesn't save in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having a problem with a super basic form in rails. All I want it to do for users to be able to change the copy in a comment (body) and I can't understand why this isn't working...

Controller:

```
def edit
@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])
    format.html { redirect_to :journal, notice: 'Comment Updated' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

View:

```
<%= render :partial => "shared/edit_comment", :locals => { 
  :comment => @comment,
  :attribute => :body }  %>
```

Form partial:

```
<%= form_for(comment) do |f| %>

        <%= f.text_area attribute, :class => "mlm mtm", :style => "color:#aaa;", 'data-widearea' => 'enable' %>  

        <%= button_tag "Save Changes", :class => 'normal caps pam mlm mtm', :style => "width: 34%;" %>
      <% end %>
```

Model if it helps:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
acts_as_nested_set :scope => [:update_id]

attr_accessible :update_id, :user_id, :body

validates_presence_of :body
validates_presence_of :user, :on => :create

# NOTE: install the acts_as_votable plugin if you
# want user to vote on the quality of comments.
#acts_as_voteable

belongs_to :update

# NOTE: Comments belong to a user
belongs_to :user

after_create :create_notification

# Helper class method that allows you to build a comment
# by passing a commentable object, a user_id, and comment text
# example in readme
def self.build_from(obj, user_id, comment)
  c = self.new
  c.update_id = obj.id
  c.body = comment
  c.user_id = user_id
  c
end

#helper method to check if a comment has children
def has_children?
  self.children.size > 0
end

# Helper class method to lookup all comments assigned
# to all commentable types for a given user.
scope :find_comments_by_user, lambda { |user|
  where(:user_id => user.id).order('created_at DESC')
}

private 

 # after a comment is created we'll create notifications for the 
 # creator of the update, as well as for anyone else who has 
 # commented as part of this update.
 def create_notification
  if update.user.id != user.id
  Notification.comment_on_update(update.user, 
                                 user.username, 
                                 user.id, 
                                 update.id, 
                                 update.notification_type, 
                                 update.game.name)
end

# efficiently retrieves all the users who have commented on this 
# update without any duplicates. then ensures that we don't add a 
# notification for the author of the new comment, or the original
# creator of the update.
update.comments.includes(["user"]).collect { |c| c.user }.uniq do |commenter|
  if (commenter.id != update.user.id) and (commenter.id != user.id)
    Notification.comment_on_comment(commenter, 
                                    user.username, 
                                    user.id,
                                    update.user.username,
                                    update.user.id,
                                    update.id,
                                    update.notification_type,
                                    update.game.name)
  end
end
end

end
```

And the output from the dev log after submitting the form:

```
Started PUT "/comments/129" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-01 19:19:16 -0700
Processing by CommentsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"bRre95bNaK0Y242yF+50TaOlBZEmuW4Lo9vDM68cOi0=", "comment"=>{"body"=>"WHY YOU NO WORK!!!!!??"}, "id"=>"129"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mComment Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "129"]]
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mUpdate Load (64.3ms)[0m  SELECT "updates".* FROM "updates" WHERE "updates"."id" = 637 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/journal
Completed 302 Found in 104ms (ActiveRecord: 66.6ms)
```

Regardless of the log, there is no change to the DB. Any ideas would be great.

Comment: what about "form for"? .. and put complete log after parameters.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working?" Is `@comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])` returning `false`?

Comment: @Gopalrathore sorry yeah, somehow the 'form for' got cut off also added more info from the log

Comment: @pdoherty926  @comment.update_attributes(params[:comment]) is returning true but the record in the DB remains unchanged.

Comment: This is simple but a gotcha we've all fallen victim to..are you looking at the same database that your server is using? dev vs. test vs. prod...

Comment: i think u should use form_for(@comment) at the place of form_for(comment)

Comment: Don't see UPDATE call in log file. You wouldn't happen to have a before_filter that might be affecting the params?

Comment: @Gopalrathore it does use form_for(@comment). It's passed through the file labeled "view" above.

Comment: @JimStewart nope, its the correct DB. I would see the update in the app in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Essentially Update is not an appropriate name for a model.

You can find more details in the links below but changing the model name to something else fixes the problem.

[Rails update_attribute isn't saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307896/rails-update-attribute-isnt-saving)

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5772-calling-a-model-update-leads-to-unexpected-behavior